# Efficient access matrix columns

Tags: c++, c, performance, matrix

Efficient access question: I need to access a large matrix (more than 2000x2000) column wise, my algorithm require a 1 row pass and 1 column pass. Row pass is fine for memory efficiency (cache miss), but how to reduce the cache miss in the column pass? I need efficiency.

The only thing I had in my is like : declare n local variable (based on memory fetch size),

`int a1, a2, a3, a4;
for ( int j = 0 ; j < DIM_Y ; j+=4 )        for ( int i = 0 ; i < DIM_X ; i++ ) 
           a1 = matrix[i][j]; ... ; a4 = matrix[i][j+4];
           // make the column processing on the 4 variables.`

It's in C or C++, and array or int or char.

Any proposition and comment is welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? Please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: What is the type of `matrix`? It's easy to assume it's a 2-D array of `int`'s, but it might also be an array of `int` pointers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Two basic techniques apply:

1) loop blocking

Instead of

```
 for (j=0;j<2000;j++)
   for (i=0;i<2000;i++) 
     process_element(i,j);
```

use

```
for (j=0;j<2000;j+=8) 
  for (i=0;i<2000;i+=8) 
    process_block_of_8x8(i,j);
```

2) non-power of 2 row stride (e.g. 8192 bytes + 64) -- pad if necessary

in this case row[i] .. row[i+7] will not fight for the same cache line

the data should be in continuous memory region with the manually calculated padding.

Comment: Doesn't that give the same amount of cache misses, unless the matrix is stored block-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to store a 2D matrix, is using a `C` style array like this:

```
| a11 a12 a13 |
| a21 a22 a23 |   -> memory: [a11,a12,a13,a21,a22,a23,a31,a32,a33]
| a31 a32 a33 | 

Element(i,j) = memory[N_COL*i+j]
```

where `i` is the row number index starting from `0`, and `j` the column number index also starting from `0`, and `N_COL` the number of columns.

Hopefully the compiler/jit is going to place all the values sequentially in memory for quick access. Usually the more you are trying to trick the compiler (like manual loop unrolling) the more you hurt yourself in performance. Write clean code and let the compiler do its thing.

Comment: This is a good approach if N_COL is not known at compile time, otherwise C supports 2-D arrays directly (as apparently used in the original question). They are no less efficient (though you do have to know all but the last dimension at compile time).

Comment: Hi Ja72, thanks, but my input matrix, it's coming from another application, and converting into an array 1st won't be memory efficient for me, 2nd won't make it faster, element at N_COL distance will have the same cache miss disadvantage.