# Performance of Handling Large Arrays in a .NET Application

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm not sure whether this is an elementary issue I'm having, but I haven't been able to sort it out for a few days now...

I am currently writing a .NET library in C# (using .NET 3.5). Among other things, it includes functions for writing a triplet of Int32 arrays (a few MB each) into a remote cache (a memcached server) and for reading back these arrays. The problem was, every implementation I could come up with took ~1.2 seconds for writing the 10MB of data and another ~1.2 seconds for reading the same data, even when the memcached server was running on the local machine.

But then, to compare the performance, I replaced the write to the cache server with just a write into the clipboard, and noticed that it still took 1.2 seconds to perform the write. I have a call to the testing method (shown below) surrounded by a `stopwatch` start/stop for benchmarking. The method is:

```
public void writeCachedImageData(int[,] atoms, int[,] noAtoms, int[,] dark, int cameraID, int runID, int seqID)
{

  Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, atoms);
  Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, noAtoms);
  Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, dark);

}
```

For benchmarking, each array was 1000x1000. Basically, my question is:

**1)** Am I correct in concluding from this test that my bottleneck is somehow the data transfer rate from the application to anything external? and

**2)** If so, what might I be able to do to improve the data transfer rate from the application to either the clipboard or, ultimately, the memcached server?

Comment: Are you running in debug mode? I know changing out the web.config to the prod version sets some flags that can help with runtime performance .... other than that I think you may have just hit the limits of your machine ... possibly

Comment: Can you remove serialisation from your writes and reads? It's possible that serialisation takes 90+% of the time. Consider using non-default serialisation methods, like protobuf

Comment: @oleksii beat me to it

Comment: Why haven't you profiled your application to see where it spends it time?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using Arrays (random access structures) and not Streams (sequential access structures)? You'll find that the vast majority of the time spend in your application is from resizing (allocating and copying) arrays. Not to mention Streams allow you to pipeline your process, whereas arrays requires you to batch and buffer your process (increasing latency on each step).

Comment: I was running in debug mode, but I've switched to release and don't see a change in the performance for this method. Also, my version of VS does not have profiling features, but I try to find another. I've also changed the method to: 'Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, atoms); Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, noAtoms); Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, dark);' and see the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice above, I tried to avoid any serialization, and did so by using BlockCopy:

```
 public void writeCachedImageData(Int16[,] atoms, int cameraID, int runID, int seqID)
    {


        byte[] bytesAtoms = new byte[2 * 1000 * 1000];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(atoms, 0, bytesAtoms, 0, bytesAtoms.Length);

        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, bytesAtoms);
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, bytesAtoms);
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, bytesAtoms);


    }
```

Note that I changed the datatype to Int16 - this is because I realized that my application did not need the other two bytes of the int type. The combination of these two has led to a more than ten times speed-up!

Answer (score 1):

Try using 1D arrays instead. They are a lot faster. So to allocate a `N×M` matrix do `var array = new Int16[N*M];` and to access the `(i,j)` element do `array[M*i+j]=...`

In my testing there is a significant improvement over 2D arrays.

If you need to, an equally fast way (albeir a bit slower) is to use jagged arrays. You allocate with `var array = new Int16[N][];` and then for each row `array[i] = new Int16[M];`. You access the contents with `array[i][j]=...`

See similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14666963/380384

If your matrices are symmetric then you can speed up things with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9040526/380384

### Code

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread()]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int N=10000;
        double t1, t2;
        {
            var array=new Int16[N, N];
            t1=ClockIt(() =>
            {
                for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
                {
                    for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
                    {
                        array[i, j]=32767;
                    }
                }
                var bytes=new byte[sizeof(Int16)*array.Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, bytes);
            });
        }
        {
            var array=new Int16[N* N];
            t2=ClockIt(() =>
            {
                for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
                {
                    for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
                    {
                        array[N*i+j]=32767;
                    }
                }
                var bytes=new byte[sizeof(Int16)*array.Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, bytes);
            });
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("t1={0}, t2={1}",t1, t2));
    }

    public static double ClockIt(this Action test)
    {
        var sw=Stopwatch.StartNew();
        test();
        sw.Stop();
        return sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

### Results (in Seconds)

```
t1=1.110093, t2=0.6908793  (61% faster)
```

I compiled a console application into *Release* mode and run it from the command window. Results are very consistent. With larger arrays the speedup is significantly more.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing serialisation from your benchmark code. It's very likely that's what causing you this trouble. But first make sure it's 100% serialisation by profiling your application. If it really is the bottleneck you can try a few tricks

- A faster serialiser, for example protobuf
- Compress your input before saving, for example with snappy/lz4/gzip
- Run serialisation in parallel with some user activity, once you understand a user wants to save things, you can prepare what to save while he/she browse for a destination folder

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. This line: `Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, atoms);` suggests that some serialisation is performed

Comment: The method gets called when one application receives some Int arrays from a camera, and wants to make them available ASAP to some other applications through the memcached server. Since it needs to run in close-to-real time, could compressing the arrays as soon as they arrive actually speed things up?